# iOS: read manually changed UIKeyboardType from UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, uikeyboardtype

I create a UITextView with a specific UIKeyboardType programmatically, lets say UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress. Now I need to read out if the User changes the UIKeyboardType manually to set the next UITextView with this value, but this does not work.

If I change the type manually and then read the UIKeyboardType in any of the UITextViewDelegates with "textView.keyboardType", i just get the initial set type "UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress".

Is it possible at all to read the manually changed Keyboardtype?

Has anyone any experience?
Thanks.

Comment: So how can a user change the keyboard? I was unaware that this was possible...

Comment: Yes, a user can change the KeyboardType to UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation, for instance, by pressing the "?.123" button at lower left.